# How to make custom height of box inside column and row in flutter

Tags: flutter, containers, row

I try to make custom box with different height that looks like this[image: custom box]

is there any guide to make box like that picture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it yourself on [dartpad](https://dartpad.dev/4e16472354bc1d9794d7e48c58a9bb6c)

```
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(32),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.lightBlue,
              ),
            ),
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Flexible(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.blue
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 16),
                Flexible(
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue
                        ),
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16),
                      Flexible(
                        child: Container(
                          color: Colors.blue
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```